# Multiple JQuery Plugins not functioning properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to get the jquery plugins timpickr and multidatespicker to work on the same page.  Unfortunately I'm having issues getting them to work together.  They are both located here:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/wiki/UiTimepickr

http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

This is my current code:

Test

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-v1.4.4.js"></script>

<!-- Start Timepickr -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/ui.timepickr.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.timepickr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $('#inTime').timepickr({convention: 12}); 
            $('#outTime').timepickr({convention: 12}); 
        }); 
    </script>
<!-- END Timepickr-->

<!-- POPUP CALENDAR --> 
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-v1.4.4.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#date').multiDatesPicker({numberOfMonths: 2});
        });
    </script>
<!-- END POPUP CALENDAR-->

    Date:  <input type="text" name="date" id="date">    
    <br>
    Time In:  <input type="text" name="inTime" id="inTime">
    <br>
    Time Out:  <input type="text" name="outTime" id="outTime">
```

Currently timepickr works.  If you add in "script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-v1.4.4.js"" right after where "!--Popup Calendar--" starts, the calendar will work but then timepickr does not.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!
-Brandon

Comment: btw, your question has nothing to do with "Java"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've been taking a serious look at the plugins and I know what your problem is.
You're missing a couple of scripts needed for the plugins to work.
Here is a solution where both plugins work, I tested it myself.
You can see in the source tags where I got the modules from, they actually came with the plugin packages.

```
<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" href="/ui-timepickr/dist/themes/default/ui.core.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" href="/ui-timepickr/dist/themes/default/ui.timepickr.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/multidates/css/mdp.css">

<!-- latest JQuery module -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- JQuery UI -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/multidates/js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/multidates/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<!-- Spanish dates -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/multidates/js/jquery.ui.datepicker-es.js"></script>

<!-- timepickr -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ui-timepickr/page/jquery.ui.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ui-timepickr/page/jquery.utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ui-timepickr/page/jquery.strings.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ui-timepickr/page/jquery.anchorHandler.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ui-timepickr/src/ui.dropslide.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ui-timepickr/src/ui.timepickr.js"></script>

<!-- datepicker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/multidates/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>

<!-- execution code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //timepickr
            $('#inTime').timepickr();
            $('#outTime').timepickr();

            //popup calendar
            $('#date').multiDatesPicker();
        });
</script>

Date:  <input type="text" name="date" id="date">    
<br>
Time In:  <input type="text" name="inTime" id="inTime">
<br>
Time Out:  <input type="text" name="outTime" id="outTime">
```

I hope that solves it for you. To make it easier, put all the necessary modules under the same directory, so you don't accidentally add a duplicate of the same script, IE, one directory for everything that has to do with JQuery, and another directory for plugins. To learn more about the plugins, I suggest you read their documentation.

Comment: While it looks alot cleaner it still doesn't work :(.  Neither work the way its currently written.  If you remove:
    "$('#inTime').timepickr({convention: 12});" 
    "$('#outTime').timepickr({convention: 12});"
The Calender will work.  If you keep those in and remove:
    "script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js""
Then the timepickr works but not the calendar.  This has been my problem all along.  one works but not the other!!! Grrr!  Thanks for trying though!

Comment: Hmm, I haven't checked the different plugins, but this is the correct way of linking them. Check if there are any duplicate functions declared between the two plugins. That can sometimes create errors but is easily fixable by changing the names. If you have Firefox with firebug you can check if there's anything going on there.

Comment: I'm still new to these Jquery plugins...  but I did install firebug and this is what it said:  http://i14.photobucket.com/albums/a302/linkenvy/firebugerrors.jpg

Comment: I've updated the post, hopefully this should resolve your problem.

Comment: Awesome!  It now works!  Now the only issue is getting the .css files to work properly.  They are both "supported" by JQuery UI Theme Roller, but apparently whenever I download a new one and use it the calendar doesn't want to work.  Its going to suck doing all that manually! hehe  Thanks!!!

Comment: Sounds like quite the hassle. The calendar is one of the strangest plugins I've seen! There are much better plugins that can do the same things but more efficiently, and also properly uses the theme roller. I'm glad the problem is resolved at least. :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again about this, but I got the .css files all fixed up and they both look good.  The only issue I have is that the multidatepicker well...  doesn't pick multiple dates.  While trying to troubleshoot it I found that if I remove jquery.ui.all.js multidatespicker works fine.  Any idea where the conflict is?  I've tried searching through the code but I haven't been able to find it yet.

Comment: I suggest you drop that plugin and use a better one instead. Like this [one](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiple.html). It's much easier to implement and it's easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Put:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>`

Directly below the first

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-v1.4.4.js"></script>`

Also remove the second jquery ui css.

Answer (score 0):

You should be putting all your JS file references together in the head of your html page for starters.  If for nothing more than readability, since you currently have doc ready statements mixed with file references.

1. jquery.js
2. jquery-ui.js
3. other.js
4. doc ready statement